# freenect - Wrong scale in the PointCloud2?

Tags: ros, calibration, kinect, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am working on implementing a kinect in my robot-arm using MoveIt. I have an *.urdf* file with the kinect as a block hovering above the robot. I launch the freenect-node, perform a static transform from the TFs created by the freenect-node to my robot and visualize everything in Rviz.

My problem is, that the scale of the pointcloud2 is off, the distances are to small. At first I thought that a calibration of the camera wouldn't be necessary and that my robot model was off, but after measuring a couple of distances in Rviz as well as in the real world, it seems the error comes from the kinect.

My question is, where should I start to fix is and what is the common practice to calibrate? Is it normal, that the point-cloud is off (The object is 2m away from the kinect, the length according to the point cloud is about 10 cm shorter than the actual length), or shouldn't the kinect be calibrated from the factory?

I am using *freenect launch* version 0.3.2 with ROS hydro on Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks in advance,

Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173259/freenect---wrong-scale-in-the-pointcloud2?/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sooo, after calibrating the RGB and the IR camera like described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration), nothing changed. I didn't expect it to work anyway.
Luckily, I tried a Asus Xtion with the same setup, which worked flawlessly. This means that the error is in my kinect. I guess I'll have to find a way to recalibrate it.

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0